# jQuery BeautyOfCode Plugin remove alerts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codehighlighter

Is possible to remove `alert()` from the plugin when brushes are not founded?

Comment: beautyOfCode: jQuery Plugin for Syntax Highlighting

Comment: I only see 2 alerts - http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shCore.js

Comment: If it's just the "annoying pop-up" factor that you want to avoid, you could divert your alerts to console (conditionally, dependent on console being present), meaning you don't have to touch core code that you may want to update some day.

Comment: @kris?? sorry don't understand if we are talking about same plugin!?

Comment: @kris me i'm talking about https://bitbucket.org/larscorneliussen/beautyofcode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment above, diverting alerts to console:

```
if (typeof(console) !== "undefined") {
  window.alert = function(content) {
    try {
      window.console.log(content); /* send alerts to console.log if available. */
    } catch(e) {}
  }
}
```

Works great for "old-school" debugging, too. You can safely use "alert" instead of "console.log" and then when you test your application in a browser that doesn't have console you can still see your debugging output.

Note: in such browsers, alert will still appear. I presume this is a good thing, because the user will need to be told that something has failed. If this is NOT a good thing, because you want to avoid the warnings altogether, the above code will not necessarily help.